# Assignment after operator []

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm learning c++ and i try to know if its possible to use assignment `=` operator after call of operator `[]`

I have an array class with private `int *_content` data, and the operator `=` overloaded.
His constructor alloc my `_content` by the size passing in parameter.

My class looks like :

```
class Array {

private:
    int *_content;

public:    
    Array(unsigned int n) {
        this->_content = new int[n];
    }

    ~Array() {
            delete[] _content;
    }

    int operator[](int n) const {
        return this->_content[n];
    }
};
```

i can write the following code :

```
int main() {
    Array a(10);

    std::cout << a[5] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result :

```
0
```

I would like to know if it's possible to assign at the case `n` of my content by any operator after using `[]` like this :

```
a[5] = 2000;
```

And know if there is any clean solution in my case for this situation.
Thank you for reply

Comment: Your `operator[]` should return a reference.

Comment: Unrelated, but it sounds weird not to keep the size of the array...

Comment: OT: you are voilating the rule of 3/5/0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, to do that you need to provide a version of `[]` that returns a *reference* to an element in the container:

```
int& operator[](int n) {
    return this->_content[n];
}
```

You can then modify the array element via that reference, with the exact syntax you propose at the calling site.

Other things going forward: You'll need to define an *assignment operator* and a copy constructor too. We call this "the rule of three". See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). And it might be an idea to capture the size of the container passed on construction. You could then check if the `n` passed to the `[]` overload is within the bounds of the backing array.

Comment: Yeah i think you speak about canonical coplien form that i just remove for this question. Thank you for the link and i will read this now ;)

Comment: Anyway the idea to capture the size is obvious and again remove for the question

Comment: @ClémentChameyrat: Awesome. I've mentioned them for the benefit of other readers, not necessarily you. And I like the term "Coplien Form", although personally I don't subscribe to it (due to the explicit destructor).

Answer (score 4):

At least you can overload the operator [] the following way

```
const int & operator[]( size_t n) const 
{
    return this->_content[n];
}

int & operator[]( size_t n) 
{
    return this->_content[n];
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare the index as `size_t` instead of `int`?

Comment: @水飲み鳥 By analogy with other standard containers. Moreover the array size is specified as size_t.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `operator[]` return a reference, then you can assign to the returned value:

```
int& operator[](int n) {
    return this->_content[n];
}
```

then you can write

```
a[5] = 100;
```

Comment: Drop the `const` though.

Answer (score 0):

of course, its possible, just let operator[] returns `int&`

```

```
int& operator[](int n) const {
    return this->_content[n];
    }
```

```

then

```
int main() {
    Array a(10);
    a[5]=1;
    std::cout << a[5] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `const` qualifier is misleading. Despite the semantics correctness.